# Creating labels where line appears in matplotlib figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, label

I have a figure created in matplotlib (time-series data) over which are a series of

```
matplotlib.pyplot.axvline
```

lines. I would like to create labels on the plot that appear close to (probably on the RHS of the line and towards the top of the figure) these vertical lines.

Comment: ax.annotate
appears it will do the job

Comment: relevant, and with a nice answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992038/inline-labels-in-matplotlib

Comment: I've posted solution for this in the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35538091/5448887)

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You can use something like

```
plt.axvline(10)
plt.text(10.1,0,'blah',rotation=90)
```

you might have to play around with the x and y value in `text` to get it to align properly.
You can find the more complete documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/text_props.html).

Comment: If you want to use data coordinates for the x-axis and axis coordinates for the y-axis, you can place the text at x=10.1 and at 50% of the height using:
`ax.text(10.1, 0.5, 'blah', rotation=90, transform=ax.get_xaxis_text1_transform(0)[0])`

Comment: Link is outdated.

Comment: If you get a "image size of … pixels is too large" error, check that your coordinates are within the y axis range (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52376517/812102).

Answer (score 35):

A solution without manual placement is to use "blended transformations".

[Transformations](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) transform coordinates from one coordinate system to another. By specifying a transformation through the `transform` parameter of [`text`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.text.html), you can give the `x` and `y` coordinates of the text in the axis coordinate system (going from 0 to 1 from left to right/top to bottom of the x/y axes, respectively). With [blended transformations](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html#blended-transformations), you can used a mixed coordinate system.

This is exactly what you need: you have the x coordinate given by the data and you want to place the text on the y axes somewhere relative to the axis, say in the center. The code to do this looks like this:

```py
import matplotlib.transforms as transforms
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# the x coords of this transformation are data, and the
# y coord are axes
trans = ax.get_xaxis_transform()

x = 10
ax.axvline(x)
plt.text(x, .5, 'hello', transform=trans)

plt.show()
```